# Spring session: session.getAttribute() value in endpointB becomes null instead of having value set in session.setAttribute() in endpointA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have two different endpoints

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void endpointA(HttpServletRequest req)
    {
      HttpSession session = req.getSession();
      session.setAttribute("targetUrl","example.com"); 
      return "redirect:authorizationUrl.com"
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login/oauth/callback", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void endpointB(HttpServletRequest req, @RequestParam("code")String authorizationCode)
    {
      HttpSession session = req.getSession();
      session.getAttribute("targetUrl");
      String sessionUrl = (String) session.getAttribute("targetUrl"); //value of targetUrl is null
      return "redirect:"+sessionUrl;
    }
```

why did the session value in `endpointB` become null instead of the value I set in `endpointA`? I would really appreciate some help on this. Thanks!